# xCode6 - how to correctly codesign unit tests in an app to deploy on device?

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, code-signing, xcode6

I'm downloading a bunch of demos from Cocoacontrols and testing them on xCode6 Beta5 with iOS8 Beta5. I'm running into an issue where a large number of apps cannot be deployed on device due to the following error:

[image]

**Is there a correct way to codesign unit tests or ask xCode6 to exclude them from deployment?**

Changing the code signing for my **main target** does not resolve the issue:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So far, deleting the "tests" target from the project fixes the error the quickest way